# Creating dynamic link for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of articles in this tableofcontent.html file, and they are all clickable links. This page works correctly, and is showing a list of all of the titles. When I click on the links though, it goes to the right template file, but none of the right data is populated in the article.html file. How do I get the data for each link to show up correctly in the articles.html page?

tableofcontent.html

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="TableofContentController">
    // non relevant code removed
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="article in data">
            <a ui-sref="article">{{article.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

article.html

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ArticlesController">
    //  non relevant code removed
    <h3>{{article.title}}</h3>
    <h6>Author: {{article.author}} on {{article.date}}</h6>
    <p>{{article.body}}</p> 
    //etc
```

app.js

```
// service to retrieve and share data

articleApp.factory('Data', function ($timeout, $http) {
    var articles = {
        fetch: function() {
            return $timeout(function() {
                return $http.get('articles.json')
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }, 30);
        }
    }
    return articles;
});


articleApp.controller('TableofContentController', function ($scope, Data) {
    Data.fetch().then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});

articleApp.controller('ArticlesController', function ($scope, Data) {
    Data.fetch().then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

also in app.js

```
// table of content state
.state('tableofcontent', {
    url: '/index',
    templateUrl: 'templates/tableofcontent.html'
})
// main articles page state
.state('article', {
    url: '/{{article.title}}',
    templateUrl: 'templates/articles.html',
    controller: 'ArticlesController',
    controllerAs: 'articles',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a bunch of issues here, what you want to do is, when someone clicks on the list of these links, instead of doing

```
<a ui-sref="article">{{article.title}}</a>
```

You probably want to do

```
<a ui-sref="article({id : article.id})">{{article.title}}</a>
```

Now that you are passing the id of the article, the modules state definition needs to be modified to accept this article id as follows.

```
.state('article', {
    url: 'article/:id',
    templateUrl: 'templates/articles.html',
    controller: 'ArticlesController',
    controllerAs: 'articles',
})
```

So now when you click on the articles, you should see a network request that looks like this : `article/1234` where 1234 is the id of the selected article.

In this example you always seem to be loading the same article.json data, but when interacting with the server you can access the selected article id by using the `$stateParams` service which you can just inject into your controller.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the advice. I'm not sure yet if it works, I've tried it, and now my site won't route to the article state. So now I have something else to fix!